# Spring Error with Form : Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean

Tags: spring, spring-form

I' m trying to make a simple form with Spring but I' ve this error and I cannot solve! I read the related questions but nothing.

This is my code please help me.

```
    package formClasses;


    public class Contact {


    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }   
}
```

this is the contacts.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

    <title>Insert Contact</title>

</head>
<body>

    <form:form action="addContact" method="POST" modelAttribute="contact">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:input path="surname" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="submit"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

the controller

```
    package controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import formClasses.Contact;

@Controller
public class contactController {

    @RequestMapping(value="addContact", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String insertContact (@ModelAttribute("contact") Contact contact, BindingResult result) {

        System.out.println("Welcome " + contact.getName() + " " + contact.getSurname());

        return "Welcome";
    }
}
```

the dispatcher

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"

    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="controllers" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
        <property name="prefix" value="../pages/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

and the web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>springform</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springform</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springform</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/springform-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

the error is

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'contact' available as request attribute
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:548)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your JSP replace:

```
<form:form action="addContact" method="POST" modelAttribute="contact">
```

By:

```
<form:form action="addContact" method="POST" commandName="contact">
```

Comment: Can you post the controller code used for displaying the form? You need to create a 'contact' object and add it to the model : model.addAttribute("contact", contact);